# Add two multiple image upload fields plupload

Tags: forms, media, files

This is the problem that i am facing.
I have 2 content types which are company and vacancies. Vacancy has an entity reference of a company.
Company content has a multiple image upload field called "images" created using plupload. vacancy content type also has a field called "vacancy images" created using plupload.

When displaying company content i have written form alter hook to load vacancies content fields programmatically into company content and i have written this form field to load "vacancy images" field.

```
        $form['field_vacancy_images'] = array(
        '#type' => 'plupload',
        '#title' => t('Vacancy Images'),
        '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg gif png')
        ),
        '#id'=>'field_vacancy_images',
        '#name'=>'field_vacancy_images',
        '#weight' => 12,

  );
```

But when i do this, image field on company content stop working. and on vacancy field Start Upload button is not appearing. What can be the reason for that?

Can anyone help me? Hope i have clearly  explained the situation.

Thanks in advance